# Why are the output colors from SVG filters squared?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I've been implementing SVG filters based on the w3 spec and when I compared my results with SVGs rendered in Chrome, Firefox and Illustrator I found that input colors for some filters seem to be squared and output colors seem to go through a square root, although alpha values do not.
For example, the spec seems to say that a feComponentTransfer filter with discrete functions could be implemented like this:

```
outputColor = tableValues[floor(inputColor * tableValues.length)]
```

But the applications I mentioned calculate it like this:

```
outputColor = sqrt(tableValues[floor(inputColor * inputColor * tableValues.length)])
```

You can see it if you open this svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="500" height="200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" baseProfile="full">
     <defs>
        <linearGradient id="redBlack">
            <stop stop-color="red" offset="0%"/>
            <stop stop-color="black" offset="100%"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="blueBlack">
            <stop stop-color="blue" offset="0%"/>
            <stop stop-color="black" offset="100%"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="greenBlack">
            <stop stop-color="lime" offset="0%"/>
            <stop stop-color="black" offset="100%"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="transparentBlack">
            <stop stop-color="rgba(0,0,0,0)" offset="0%"/>
            <stop stop-color="black" offset="100%"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <g id="gradientImage">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="50" fill="url(#redBlack)"/>
            <rect x="0" y="50" width="500" height="50" fill="url(#blueBlack)"/>
            <rect x="0" y="100" width="500" height="50" fill="url(#greenBlack)"/>
            <rect x="0" y="150" width="500" height="50" fill="url(#transparentBlack)"/>
        </g>
        <filter id="componentDiscrete" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
            <feImage xlink:href="#gradientImage" result="test1" />
            <feComponentTransfer in="test1">
                <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1"/>
                <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1"/>
                <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1"/>
                <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1"/>
            </feComponentTransfer>
        </filter>
     </defs>
     <rect x="0"  y="0" width="500" height="200" filter="url(#componentDiscrete)"/>
</svg>
```

I've also seen it in feTurbulence. I implemented it using the code in the spec but I have to square the output of that code to get a result that matches the applications that I have tried.

Why square the input and take the root of the output?

Comment: Color spaces can mess with your results. The default color space for SVG Filters is linearRGB (although when you reference them with a CSS filter they use sRGB). LinearRGB is an uncommon color space. Add "color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" into the browser code and I'm guessing that you will  probably get something closer to your implementation.